# Alternative to foreach MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large array.  Is there an alternate method to check if `$value` in the array is present in the MySql table `vote` and if not then insert `$value` into `vote`. This is what i am doing currently.  Is there a better method?

```
foreach($rowids as $value) {


        $select = mysql_query("SELECT voteid FROM vote WHERE username='$username' AND voteid='$value' LIMIT 1",$this->connect);

            if(mysql_num_rows($select)==0) {

        $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vote VALUES ('','$value','$username')",$this->connect);

            }
        }
```

Comment: You could simply attempt the insert and handle the error, assuming the appropriate unique constraints are in place

Comment: in most cases you would want to store a userid, instead of a varchar username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a [UNIQUE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) on `(value,username)` then you could use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO vote (foo,voteid,username) VALUES ('','$value','$username')
```

---

To add a UNIQUE INDEX:

```
ALTER TABLE vote ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx (voteid,username)
```

This will fail if there are "duplicate" rows in `vote` that violate the UNIQUE INDEX. To drop duplicate rows and add the UNIQUE INDEX at the same time:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE vote ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx (voteid,username)
```

Comment: thanks..is this a better method performance wise for hundreds of users?

Comment: I think this must be better than issuing 2 queries + equivalent logic in PHP. Moreover, a few hundred inserts should pose no problem at all for any database.